# Unchecking Selected Date in Calendar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I have a asp calendar utility in ascx page. I want to unselect the selected date on second click on the same date. The following are my codes. Kindly help in this.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeFile="Calendar.ascx.cs"Inherits="WebUserControl" %>

 <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="100%">

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyear" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">

                <asp:ListItem Text="2014" Value="2014" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2015" Value="2015"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2016" Value="2016"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2017" Value="2017"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2018" Value="2018"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2019" Value="2019"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2020" Value="2020"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2021" Value="2021"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2022" Value="2022"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2023" Value="2023"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2024" Value="2024"></asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="100%" dir="ltr">

        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" 
            onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" 
          >
        <HeaderTemplate>

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Month") %>' Visible="false" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  NextPrevFormat="CustomText"  SelectionMode="Day"    NextMonthText="" PrevMonthText=""    Font-Names="A" OtherMonthDayStyle-BorderStyle="NotSet" OtherMonthDayStyle-Wrap="False" OtherMonthDayStyle-ForeColor="#CCCCCC">
            <TitleStyle  
                 BackColor="#6EC347" 
                 ForeColor="White"
                 Height="36"  
                 Font-Size="Large"  
                 Font-Names="Arial"  
                 />  
                  <SelectedDayStyle  
                 BackColor="Green"  
                 BorderColor="SpringGreen"  
                 />  
            </asp:Calendar>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

My code behind for this ascx page is

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
int month = 1;
public event EventHandler YearChanged;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadcalendar();

    }

}
private void loadcalendar()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("January");
    dt.Rows.Add("February");
    dt.Rows.Add("March");
    dt.Rows.Add("April");
    dt.Rows.Add("May");
    dt.Rows.Add("June");
    dt.Rows.Add("July");
    dt.Rows.Add("August");
    dt.Rows.Add("September");
    dt.Rows.Add("October");
    dt.Rows.Add("Novemeber");
    dt.Rows.Add("December");

    DataList1.DataSource = dt;
    DataList1.DataBind();

}

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
          e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        string year = ddlyear.SelectedValue.ToString();
        String str = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("txt1")).Text;

        DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime TempDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), month, 1);

        // DateTime TempDate = new DateTime(Now.Year,Now.Month, 1);
        ((Calendar)e.Item.FindControl("Calendar1")).VisibleDate = TempDate;
        month = month + 1;
    }

}

protected void ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        loadcalendar();
        YearChanged(sender, e);


}
```

}

My Aspx.cs page code is like this

```
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
        cnn.ConnectionString = connStr;
        cnn.Open();
        string eid;
        string ename = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (ename == "1")
        {
            eid = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            eid = "2";
        }
        int cid = Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        //String sqlSelect = String.Format("Select Customer_Id from Customer where Customer_Name='{0}'", cname);
        //SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, cnn);
        //int cid = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        DataList dl;
        dl = ((DataList)patchCalendar.FindControl("DataList1"));


        foreach (DataListItem dli in dl.Items)
        {
                string month = Convert.ToString(((Label)dli.FindControl("txt1")).Text);
                string day = Convert.ToString(((Calendar)dli.FindControl("Calendar1")).SelectedDate.Day);
                string year = Convert.ToString(((Calendar)dli.FindControl("Calendar1")).SelectedDate.Year);
                string date = ((Calendar)dli.FindControl("Calendar1")).SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
                if (date == "1/1/0001")
                {
                    year = null;
                    date = null;
                    day = null;
                }
                else
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Patching_Dates values(@cid,@eid,@year,@month,@day,@date)", cnn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", eid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
        }
        cnn.Close();
        string act = "Patching Dates Added";
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Logs values(@Username,@Activity,@Time)", cnn);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", (string)(Session["user"]));
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", act);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: See this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627716/deselect-dates-in-asp-net-calendar-control this will help you!!

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama No this is not working

Comment: are you handling same thing in selected index changed?

Comment: is that selected changed index firing when you click on same date again?

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama how to check that ?

Answer (score 0):

First check Calendar1 control having value if yes then reset it by this

```
Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear();
```

Comment: My calendar is in ascx file.