# Deselecting date in asp.net Calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar, c#-3.0

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Calendar.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="100%">

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyear" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">

                <asp:ListItem Text="2014" Value="2014" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2015" Value="2015"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2016" Value="2016"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2017" Value="2017"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2018" Value="2018"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2019" Value="2019"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2020" Value="2020"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2021" Value="2021"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2022" Value="2022"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2023" Value="2023"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2024" Value="2024"></asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="100%" dir="ltr">

        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" 
            onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" 
          >
        <HeaderTemplate>

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Month") %>' Visible="false" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  NextPrevFormat="CustomText"  SelectionMode="Day"    NextMonthText="" PrevMonthText=""    Font-Names="A" OtherMonthDayStyle-BorderStyle="NotSet" OtherMonthDayStyle-Wrap="False" OtherMonthDayStyle-ForeColor="#CCCCCC" >
            <TitleStyle  
                 BackColor="#6EC347" 
                 ForeColor="White"
                 Height="36"  
                 Font-Size="Large"  
                 Font-Names="Arial"  
                 />  
                  <SelectedDayStyle  
                 BackColor="Green"  
                 BorderColor="SpringGreen"  
                 />  
            </asp:Calendar>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The corresponding ascx.cs file is

```
    public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    int month = 1;
    public event EventHandler YearChanged;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadcalendar();

        }

    }
    private void loadcalendar()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("January");
        dt.Rows.Add("February");
        dt.Rows.Add("March");
        dt.Rows.Add("April");
        dt.Rows.Add("May");
        dt.Rows.Add("June");
        dt.Rows.Add("July");
        dt.Rows.Add("August");
        dt.Rows.Add("September");
        dt.Rows.Add("October");
        dt.Rows.Add("Novemeber");
        dt.Rows.Add("December");

        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
              e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            string year = ddlyear.SelectedValue.ToString();
            String str = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("txt1")).Text;

            DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime TempDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), month, 1);

            // DateTime TempDate = new DateTime(Now.Year,Now.Month, 1);
            ((Calendar)e.Item.FindControl("Calendar1")).VisibleDate = TempDate;
            month = month + 1;
            //((Calendar)e.Item.FindControl("Calendar1")).SelectedDates.Clear();
        }

    }

    protected void ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            loadcalendar();
            YearChanged(sender, e);

    }

}
```

I need to deselect date once it is clicked again. This code will display 12 months calendar in the page. I read in some forums that i should give my code in calendar_selectedchange event. How to use in my code? Also if there is anyother way to deselect date with the following code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627716/deselect-dates-in-asp-net-calendar-control ?

Answer (score 1):

Using this code helped to solve the problem:

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001");
```

Comment: It would seem to me that this would then change the selection to `"01/01/0001"`? I'm not sure if that's what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I believe they are looking to clear it.  I think the DateTimePicker only goes back to 1601?

Comment: When you select a date on calendar this date remains selected and if you click in another date it will select another date on calendar. When you set the selectedDate to "01/01/0001" you will erase this selection. It works like a nullvalue to selectedDate.

Comment: Thank you. Searched the entire web for 2 days to search for the solution. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to select multiple dates, so

[here's the solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/1650106.aspx?Deselect%20a%20selected%20date%20on%20a%20second%20click) (asp.net forums)

[here's the theory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfasf5wy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (msdn)

EDIT (again)

```
 <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" onSelectionChanged="onSelectionChanged"
OnDayRender="onDayRender">
```

codebehind

```
    int month = 1;
    public event EventHandler YearChanged;

    //I've stored the selected date in the session.
    //There are others workaround, like saving it in the ViewState or in a db
    private DateTime yourDates
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime)Session["yourDates"];
        }
        set
        {
            Session["yourDates"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //always clear the session at start
            yourDates = new DateTime();
        }

    }

    protected void onSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime selectedDate = (sender as Calendar).SelectedDate;

        if (yourDate == selectedDate)
        {
            yourDate = new DateTime();
            //it is vital to clear the selection to trigger this method again
            (sender as Calendar).SelectedDates.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            yourDate = selectedDate;
            (sender as Calendar).SelectedDates.Clear();
        }
    }


    protected void onDayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.Date == yourDate)
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
```

The `onDayRender()` method is called for every calendar cell.

Comment: I want to delselect the selected date

Comment: That I understood, it's not clear why you want to do that.
You want to 'check/uncheck' dates from your calendar?
You want to stop the form from postbacking if a date is not selected?

Comment: This code will display 12 months calendar in my page suppose if one month i want to remove date i shud be able to do that.

Comment: i worked with your code. The date is not getting deselected. when i click the selected date again. also Multiple dates are getting selected.

Comment: actually if you debug you'll see that the dates are getting deselected every time you select a new date and there's just the green cell remaining - as I specified in my code.

The problem here is that when you select a date you can't trigger the `onSelectionChanged` method, so I've figured a way to store the selection in another way.

You want just **one** date selected? I'll change my code, it gets easier too.

Comment: yes i need only one date selected for one month. Also i want remove green cell.

Comment: done. Remember that you'll have to get the selected date from session, not from the calendar.

Comment: why are you storing it in session ?

Comment: The `Calendar` control prevents the `selecteddate` cell to trigger the `onSelectingDate` method.

I set the cell as not selected to trigger the method again, and to rietrieve the value for another use I've stored it in the session.

Comment: There is one more problem now. I cant select more than one month's date

Comment: yeah, it's the same calendar. You can't select two dates from the same calendar, my previous code was intended to do that but you wanted it changed.